# UI component form

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I have problem with Magento UI component form.

When I click on this form and save it database with this row will be updated. Second time when I entered on that same slider, the values are checked but problem is when I want to save that instance, then every data from form RELATED banners disappear.

In POST form I don't have any values from form "Related Banners" - very propably that it's caused by ui component. How can I pass data (for example Checked column (checked/unchecked)) to save Action after edit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your controller. I assume the Related banners section is ajax based. So when you come for the second time you are not doing here anything and if you save the related banners will be `null` so null will be saved and values will be unchecked.

You should add some condition in your controller something like this.

```
If(isset($data['related_banners'])){

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I don't think so it's the problem. When I come for the second time and I have selected one checkbox and after that I want to select another,  then I save slider, first checkbox in POST Data is not visible as selected... only the second one